# mv renaming files deleted it

Tags: command-line, 20.04, files, mv, undelete

if i had a playlist filled with music, i would want it to shuffle and play because i wouldn't want to hear the same song order over and over again as it gets old real fast.. same thing here but with pictures

so i wanted my files randomized
and i looked up a command to randomize file names and i got this

```
for file in *.jpg; do
mv -- "$file" "$RANDOM-$RANDOM-$RANDOM.jpeg"
done
```

it worked well but the problem was that it only changed jpeg so i did this

```
for file in *.jpg; do
mv -- "$file" "$RANDOM-$RANDOM-$RANDOM.jpeg"
done

for file in *.jpeg; do
mv -- "$file" "$RANDOM-$RANDOM-$RANDOM.jpg"
done

for file in *.JPG; do
mv -- "$file" "$RANDOM-$RANDOM-$RANDOM.png"
done
```

i ran this command as a shell script and it removed all files from the folder. And no where to be found.
i also ran it in a removable disk

**EDIT:**

It just turned out to be a visual glitch and a power outage fixed it.

The reason why i took so long to edit this is cause my boot got corrupted and it took really long to fix it.

Thanks to anyone who tried to help.

Comment: From your question "i wanted to randomize file names on my folder so do go through it in the same order everytime i go through it." What does this mean.

Comment: if i have a playlist filled with music, i would want it to shuffle and play because i wouldn't want to hear the same song order over and over again  as it gets old real fast.. same thing here but with pictures

Comment: Then that is what the question should have said. I suggest you edit and re word your question.

Comment: It seems you changed all your `*.JPG` files to `*.png`. So you'll want to look for `*.png` files and not `*.JPG`.

Comment: uhmm i had all three file types in my folder so i wanted to rename and randomize all three of those file types thats why the command is repeating with different file types. i dont think it all will change into one file type

Comment: it randomized the name of the file so i dont know the name of it to search for it

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how exactly you ran these commands. Did you type the commands in a terminal window? Did you run a shell script? Did you copy&paste the commands exactly as you ran them to the question? Does "*it removed all files from the folder*" mean that the folder is now empty? How did you check this? The commands shown in the question should only rename files and would ask for confirmation if two files would get the same random name. I guess you also ran other commands not shown in the question. BTW: The third command will rename `*.JPG` files to **`.png`**.

Comment: @bruh: it is `ls *.png`. And the error is in the "for' of the last one: `for file in *.JPG; do` should have been `for file in *.png; do`

Comment: Although there is a *small* probability that `$RANDOM-$RANDOM-$RANDOM` generates non-unique names in bash, the only way I can see that your commands would have "deleted" *all* your files (well, technically *overwritten* all but 3 of them) would be if you ran the commands in a shell that does not provide the `RANDOM` builtin variable, so that `$RANDOM` returns the empty string. When run using `/bin/sh` for example, you'd end up with 3 files named `--.jpeg`, `--.jpg`, `--.png`. The `mv` command won't stop you doing that unless run with the `-n`/`--no-clobber` or `-i`/`--interactive` option.

Comment: @Bodo i ran it in a shell script. the command doesnt look like it deletes or remove files but it did.

Comment: @steeldriver the commands given above is exactly the way its written in the shell script. idk if RANDOM is a builtin variable in the shell script

Comment: @bruh so what shebang did you use in the script? How exactly did you run it? Have you checked for files of the names I mentioned?

Comment: @steeldriver 
i pasted those commands in a txt file and saved it as .sh. i ran it and what i saw was names of files in the folder turning into a bunch of numbers and letters and slowly disappearing one by one. i ran this sricpt in a removable device so im not sure if its in my main disk or the removable one, that is if it moved to somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the *Python* programming language for this very easily:

```
import glob
import random

# reads in from the current folder the files with the pattern *.mp3 and assign it to a variable of type list.
music_files = glob.glob("*.mp3")

# is picking randomnized a file from the variable.
random_music_file = random.choice(music_files)
```

*Python* is installed up front on each Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Welcome! The OP asked about renaming image files. How does this even get close? Also, you should explain what the script does if it's universally applicable.

Comment: @ArturMeinild, he talks of music files as well as of image files.

Comment: +1: Looks like the OP asked an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). For the original, underlying problem, this is a good answer. How to answer an XY Question is always a challenge. The BEST option would be if the OP fixed their question, but we know that's rare.

Comment: As I read it, the underlying question/problem is that the OP lost his files - which have absolutely nothing to do with what he was originally trying to do. And yeah, we can't really do anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

To possibly locate your files, with five digits and a dash in the name, with a name end with jpg:

First do
`$ sudo updatedb` - to freshen the database...  then
`$ locate --regex "[0-9]{5}-.*jpg$"`

Oh, and **prior** to those you need e.g.
`$ sudo apt install mlocate` - if you haven't already done it.

*One more thing: if PRUNEPATHS= in `/etc/updatedb.conf` happens to contain the path where the files are, they won't be shown.*

Comment: im not sure what the output is supposed to be but i got nothing. i ran the command in terminal and there were no output

Comment: The output (from `locate`) would be paths and names of your jpg files, if `sudo apt updatedb` includes them in the database. i.e. PRUNEPATHS in /etc/updatedb.conf tells which paths NOT to include - by default, one path among those is `/media/*`